# Mongoose reference between attributes

Tags: node.js, mongodb, orm, mongoose, schema

I have some Schemas in mongoose as follows:

```
var tournamentSchema = new Schema({
    name:       {type: String},
    teams:      [teamSchema],
    poules:     [pouleSchema],
    createdAt:  {type: Date, default: Date.now}
})

var pouleSchema = new Schema({
    teams:      [teamSchema],
    createdAt:  {type: Date, default: Date.now}
})

var teamSchema = new Schema({
    name:       {type: String},
    createdAt:  {type: Date, default: Date.now}
})
```

I will push some teams in my tournamentSchema. When ready, I want to create the poules with the teams.

Is it possible to make a relation between the 'tournamentSchema.teams' and the 'tournamentSchema.poules'? I think it is not that difficult to push teams in the poules attribute, but when I want to change a name of a team, I want to change it in the poules also. Should I do this manually or is there some relation possible?

Or is this only possible with different Models?

Thank you in advance,

Ronald.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think mongoose population can help you. Try something like this:

```
var tournamentSchema = new Schema({
    name:       {type: String},
    teams:      [teamSchema],
    poules:     [pouleSchema],
    createdAt:  {type: Date, default: Date.now}
})

var pouleSchema = new Schema({
    teams:      [teamSchema],
    createdAt:  {type: Date, default: Date.now}
})

var teamSchema = new Schema({
    team: {
       type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
       ref: 'teamsSchema'
    }
})

var teamsSchema = new Schema({
    name:       {type: String},
    createdAt:  {type: Date, default: Date.now}
})
```

So every object in your teams array referencing to ObjectId in teamsSchema, and when you change name of team it will automatically affects on teams arrays. Hope it will help you.

Comment: Ok, thank you! I tried this, but how can I add a team right now? I made a tournament and then I searched it by ID. In the callback I get tournament and did: tournament.teams.push({ name: 'Test Team' }). But I'll get an "_id" back, but no name...

Comment: Is it possible to do this with one model? So there is only a 'Tournament' model (mongoose.model('Tournament', tournamentSchema)). Or is it necessary to make a specific model for Teams?

Comment: You need to have teams collection with their _id, name, createdAt fields, as it is described in teamsSchema. Then in your tournament.teams you should have array of objects like {team: someObjectId}, as described in teamSchema. someObjectId refers to one of team _id from teams collection. Then when you query your tournaments you should populate your teams.team. Please, read about mongoose population and it will be clear for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know something about the populate function, but that is between models. I want to create one model 'Tournament' and store everything in there. But I can't find out if it possible to populate inside a model itself. If that isn't possible I have to create a model for Teams and a model for Tournaments.

Comment: But why you want to store teams in tournament collection? I think , it is wrong approach to problem solving.

Comment: Yes, I know. But that was my question. I thought maybe there is an easy way. In the front-end I have to work with one JSON object, because it is a webapp. I made an API to work with. And it's a tournament with teams and matches and poules, so it's a deep nested object. But I'll make models for each object and then link them together. Thank you for your time to answer my questions.

Comment: The result of population will be one JSON object too. So use this feature. And you are welcome.

Comment: I'll do. It's going quite well right now. Thank you. This was my first post. Do I have to close it or something?